# Copy values upon checking a box and disable the old edited cells after the edit

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

When a check box in cell A2 is checked by the user, copy Cell C2 value of the row to the target sheet Cell D7. If user check the box A3 it should copy C3 to target sheet Cell D7 and the same for every cell in column A except for the header.

If I already check the box of A2 and copied the C2 details that means A2 should never be clickable again. but all others like A3 A4 and so on still able to override the D7 value. But script should not work for A2 after A3 is checked.

Here is the source sheet:

[image]

and the target sheet:

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10jR6Nap_C3D5noS8rnkQJ7k7-eTOpmadKKp2bxv7Xr8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: A5 and even for new entries like A6 and all. actually, entire column A accept A1 which is a header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

You have two goals:

1. You want to be able to copy the data from **column A** of the source sheet to the cell **D7**.

Essentially, you need to get the value of the active row and **column C** and set it to cell **D7**:

```
targetSheet.getRange('D7').setValue(as.getRange(arow,3).getValue());
```

2. You want to block the cells that were used before, so if an old cell is used, the `onEdit` trigger want copy the data to cell **D7**. For this particular scenario, you need to take advantage of the [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service#getDocumentProperties()) class. You will store the cells that you have edited in the past, so if the newly edited cell is part of this list, don't copy the data, otherwise copy it to cell **D7**.

### **Solution:**

I copied the solution to your file and tested it and it works as expected. You don't need to do anything. The code will be executed upon edits.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const ss = e.source;
  const as = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const ar = e.range;
  const arow = ar.getRow();
  const acol = ar.getColumn();
  
  if (ar.getValue() == true && as.getName() == "get" && acol == 1 && arow > 1){
    console.log("mpika")
    const ncell = ar.getA1Notation();
    const check = getHistory(ncell);
    console.log(check)

    if(check) {
      const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("target");
      targetSheet.getRange('D7').setValue(as.getRange(arow,3).getValue());
    }
  }
}

function getHistory(ncell) {
  const cprop = PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperty("edited_cells")
  if(cprop){
    if(cprop.includes(ncell)){
      return false;
    }
    else{
      PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty("edited_cells",`${cprop},${ncell}`)
      return true;
    }
  }
  else{
    PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().setProperty("edited_cells",ncell);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: yes its working but now the problem is if I click lets say A4 its copy the C4 to the target and same for A5 but if go to A4 again and uncheck and check it again it copies C4 value again. what here is need is to disable the A4 once it checked

Comment: @AliAhmed so after `D7` gets a value, you want essentially to disable the script right? any edits on checkboxes will keep the value in D7 the same right?

Comment: No not that. what i want is. If I already check the box of A2 and copied the C2 details that means A2 should never be clickable again. but all others like A3 A4 and so on still able to override the D7 value. But script should not work for A2 after A3 is checked

Comment: i coppied your code to my original sheet and rename sheet names and getting e.source undefined error upon running the script on both the sheets

Comment: @AliAhmed you are not supposed to run the `onEdit` function manually. It is a trigger function and it is executed automatically upon user edits. Think about it. What would be the purpose of a trigger function if you had to execute it manually.  The solely purpose of trigger functions are to be executed by user or time events so you don't have to run it by yourself. Please read about triggers in the official documentation : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#:~:text=Triggers%20let%20Apps%20Script%20run,%2C%20Slides%2C%20or%20Forms%20file.

Comment: @AliAhmed and if you have more questions please avoid asking them in the comment section. stackoverflow does not allow for follow up questions. Think about it, we are here to create an online repository for future readers. The future reader won't be benefit from the comment section. Nobody reads the comments here. Post a new question if you can not figure the issue to your problem yourself as a separate post.